# Is the DNS feature of Win2k8r2 useful in a home network?

Tags: dns, home-networking, windows-server-2008

I guess the title says it all.

I have the server with the specified OS, and 3 PC's maximum.

Can I safely disable the DNS feature in the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using the server for? Do you have an Active Directory? If so, then no. Absolutally not.

Otherwise, it depends on the servers purpose. What are you doing with a 2k8r2 server in a home environment with 3 computers anyway? Seems like an awfully expensive way of doing things...

Comment: It could be that he has an MSDN or Technet subscription, or he may be a Microsoft Registered Partner with a MAPS subscription. I have a MAPS subscription and that's why I run W2K8 on my home network.

Comment: I have created Active Directory users for the other PCs; and I'm playing with this server and my home PCs so I get to learn more about networks (nothing wrong about that I hope). So what does the DNS really do in that case?

Comment: It allows Active Directory to work: `DNS is used by Active Directory for domain controller location and DNS naming is leveraged by Active Directory for domain naming.` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781627(WS.10).aspx

Comment: ok thx a lot for your answers guys

Answer (score 0):

It's useful if you want to have internal name resolution. I use a W2K8 server internally for DNS and DHCP for all of my home computers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with joe. I use w2k3 server at work an an ubuntu server at home (9.04 LTS) and I use DNS on both for internal addressing and for DNS forwarding. However, not everyone who wants a home sever needs to run all the services we geeks use! :-p